# How do I change the color of hidden files in MacOS Finder?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, color

In Monterey (and probably earlier MacOS versions) the Finder displays hidden files - and files which are on cloud storage but not downloaded – in light gray.
(That **⌘⇧.** shortcut isn't well-publicized, but at least it exists.)

So depending on the background stripes in the Finder window, the filenames, dates, and sizes are shown as light gray on white, or even more idiotically, light gray on gray.

[image: hidden files, visible but only just]

I'm past my thirties now, so I can't easily read all this low contrast gray on gray crap.
(And yes, I *do* use the Terminal most of the time instead.)

Is there a setting in Finder (or some property in the plist) to change the color for hidden files to say, blue or red?

Comment: I can't find a solution. And I have looked at some 3rd-party Finder replacements - all make hidden files grey.